# Svelte contenteditable is not updated properly

Tags: svelte

I created spreadsheet with Svelte, but it seems like it won't update the cell properly.

I appended the "2" postfix to every cell, and when I edit the content (say to fix first letter in jim to be uppercased) it should end up with two "2" as "Jim22". But it end up with just one "2" as "Jim2".

I also have JSON output to inspect the value of `rows`, and it changed, so the component was updated correctly, but the editable cell was not updated to "Jim22" it still "Jim2".

Why, and how to fix that?

[playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/e023f0e99eeb41189cca7a005f7967b5?version=3.38.2)

[image]

Code

```
<script>
  let rows = [
    ["jim"],
    ["Kate"]
  ]

  function update(i, j, event) {
        rows[i][j] = event.target.innerText
  }
</script>

<table>
  {#each rows as row, i}
    <tr>
      {#each row as cell, j}
        <td contenteditable="true" on:blur="{(event) => update(i, j, event)}">{cell}2</td>
      {/each}
    </tr>
  {/each}
</table>

<pre>{JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2)}</pre>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I found that `<td>{@html cell}2</td>` solves the problem. Looking for the explanation.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work either but `<td>{cell + "2"}</td>` works as well. Also, what's interesting is that when you initially load your playground and then inspect the `<td>` it displays `"Jim"` and then `"2"` on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Long Vu's answer is the root cause of the problem, because it cannot explain why the modification mentioned in the comments of the question works. Adding keys is rather a workaround.

After some debugging and searching, I found this issue: [Repeat words in plain text aren't reactive](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5931). When trying to update `"Jim"` to `"Jim2"`, svelte uses [`set_data` function](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/6d16e9260642b1fcc70fa4a24be9fd49985112d1/src/runtime/internal/dom.ts#L196), which compares `text.wholeText === data`. While `text.data` is `"Jim"`,  `text.wholeText` and `data` are both `"Jim2"`, so the update is skipped.

[About `wholeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/wholeText):

> The `Text.wholeText` read-only property returns the full text of all `Text` nodes logically adjacent to the node.

So, by inspecting `childNodes` property of `td`:

- `<td>{cell}2</td>` has two `Text` nodes: `"Jim"` and `"2"`, and `wholeText` is `"Jim2"`
- `<td>{cell + "2"}</td>` has one `Text` node, no problem
- `<td>{@html cell}2</td>` is not using `set_data` function, fine

Also as said in the issue, downgrading svelte to v3.23.2 makes `<td>{cell}2</td>` work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the key for each statement. according to [document](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)

```
<script>
  let rows = [
    ["Jim",  "Raynor"],
    ["Kate", "Bishop"]
  ]

  function update(i, j, event) {
        rows[i][j] = event.target.innerText
  }
</script>

<table>
  {#each rows as row, i (row)}
    <tr>
      {#each row as cell, j (cell)}
        <td contenteditable="true" on:blur="{(event) => update(i, j, event)}">{cell}2</td>
      {/each}
    </tr>
  {/each}
</table>

<pre>{JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2)}</pre>
```